# How to convert Nested dict of dicts to mupltiple columns using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a JSON file with dicts in dict. I converted it to DataFrame:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|data                                                                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[GUID -> 132, terms -> {"data1":{"data1_1":"test1","data1_2":"test2"}, "data2"-> {"data1":{"data2_1":"test2"}]                  |
|[GUID -> 123213, terms -> {"data1":{"data1_1":"test1","data1_2":"test2"}, "data2"-> {"data1":{"data2_1":"test2"}]               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How to convert the DF above to miltiple columns?

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
| GUID | terms_data1_data1_1 | terms_data1_data1_2 |  terms_data2_data2_1 | 
+------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
| 132  |  test1              |      test2          |      test2           |
|123213|  test1              |      test2          |      test2           |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: What did the JSON file look like before you converted it to a DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you reformat your data to:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, MapType, StructType, StructField

data = [
    (132, 
      {
        "data1": {"data1_1": "test1", "data1_2": "test2"}, 
        "data2": {"data2_1": "test2"}
      }
    ),
    (123213, 
      {
        "data1": {"data1_1": "test1", "data1_2": "test2"}, 
        "data2": {"data2_1": "test2"}
      }
    )
]
```

and feed to a `createdDataFrame` with a `schema` like:

```
data = [
    (132, {"data1": {"data1_1": "test1", "data1_2": "test2"}, "data2": {"data2_1": "test2"}}),
    (123213, {"data1": {"data1_1": "test1", "data1_2": "test2"}, "data2": {"data2_1": "test2"}})
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("GUID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("terms", MapType(StringType(), MapType(StringType(), StringType())), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

result = df \
    .withColumn("terms_data1_data1_1", df["terms"].getItem("data1").getItem("data1_1")) \
    .withColumn("terms_data1_data1_2", df["terms"].getItem("data1").getItem("data1_2")) \
    .withColumn("terms_data2_data2_1", df["terms"].getItem("data2").getItem("data2_1")) \
    .drop("terms")

result.show()
```

with this I get the required output.